# NuGet Pack in TeamCity Missing Dependent Assemblies

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package, teamcity-9.0

In TeamCity, I'm trying to create a NuGet package. It works, however only the main EXE is included in the package. When it gets deployed to a server, the dependent assemblies are missing, and so is the config file. I don't see an option to included the dependent assemblies. Is there a way to do so?

Instead of a nuspec file, I'm using the csproj file. The screenshot, below, shows that and the rest of the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include additional files with your nuget package, *.nuspec file is obligatory. It should be in the same directory as your *.csproj file:

- Your.Library.csproj
- Your.Library.csproj.nuspec

Please refer to this documentation about adding files to nuget package: [Adding a readme and other files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#adding-a-readme-and-other-files)

Comment: Is this still necessary for dependent assemblies? I'm not looking to add some stray file; just the assemblies on which my project depends. I was hoping `IncludeReferencedProjects` would help, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's true that nuspec is obligatory. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384248/279516